# Android Studio xml layout autocomplete not working

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, autocomplete, intellisense

I'm using Android Studio version 2021.1
as shown  bellow in the GIF the auto-complete doesn't work if I changed the "ConstraintLayout" to any other layout such as "LinearLayout" or "RelativeLayout", but it works just fine with "ConstraintLayout".

---

[image]

What i've tried so far is:

1. Deleting AS cache from `~/AppData/Local/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/caches`
2. Deleting `.idea` from my project
3. Creating new xml layout :/

Comment: I had the compileSdk set to 33 (targetSdk) and changing compileSdk to 21 (minSdk), did the trick but I don't think that it's quite right :/, if someone can explain how does changing the "compileSdk" solved the problem or has a better solution please tell me

Comment: have you tried `invalidate cache` and `restart`?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it wasn't of much help. And I just realized that changing "complieSdk" gave me Errors while building the app "One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values"